# Downsample to quarter level and get quarter end date value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

my data frame has daily value from 2005-01-01 to 2021-10-31.

```
            | C1     | C2
-----------------------------
2005-01-01  | 2.7859 | -7.790
2005-01-02  |-0.7756 | -0.97
2005-01-03  |-6.892  | 2.770
2005-01-04  | 2.785  | -0.97
.           .         .
.           .         .
2021-10-28  | 6.892  | 2.785
2021-10-29  | 2.785  | -6.892  
2021-10-30  |-6.892  | -0.97
2021-10-31  |-0.7756 | 2.34
```

I want to downsample this data frame to get quarter value  as follows.

```
            | C1     | C2
------------------------------
2005-03-01  | 2.7859 | -7.790
2005-06-30  |-0.7756 | -0.97
2005-09-30  |-6.892  | 2.770
2005-12-31  | 2.785  | -0.97
```

I tried to do it with Pandas resample method but it requires an aggregation method.

```
df = df.resample('Q').mean()
```

I don't want the aggregated value I want the current value at the quarter-end date as it is.

Comment: Do you Mean 2005-03-31 ?

Comment: @anarchy, I couldn't get you. I want the daily value data frame to filter down to quarter-end date rows.

Comment: Look at your example, you wrote 2005-03-01, that’s the first day of March, it should be 2005-03-31 yes? Check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code works except you are not using the right function. Replace `mean` by `last`:

```
dti = pd.date_range('2005-01-01', '2021-10-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((len(dti), 2)), columns=['C1', 'C2'], index=dti)

dfQ = df.resample('Q').last()
print(dfQ)

# Output:
                  C1        C2
2005-03-31  0.653733  0.334182
2005-06-30  0.425229  0.316189
2005-09-30  0.055675  0.746406
2005-12-31  0.394051  0.541684
2006-03-31  0.525208  0.413624
...              ...       ...
2020-12-31  0.662081  0.887147
2021-03-31  0.824541  0.363729
2021-06-30  0.064824  0.621555
2021-09-30  0.126891  0.549009
2021-12-31  0.126217  0.044822

[68 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This absolutely solved it for me, and I'm surprised it had 0 upvotes when I encountered it. Thank you!

Comment: @User356. Glad this code helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
df = df[df.index.is_quarter_end]
```

You will filter out the dates only at the end of each quarter.

Comment: Does it work? @sekinod

Comment: @anarchy. Your code doesn't give the last date (2021-12-31) and I don't understand why... Try it on my sample. FIY, you don't need `.loc` here.

Comment: @sekinod yeah i wasnt supposed to add .loc here, does my code work now ?